# Looking for set number - lots of off green flat pieces

Tags: set-identification

Looking for kit that these bags belong to

[image: lots of darker green flat pieces]

Answer (score 6):

These are from [The Child (75318)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75318-1) set. Identified by unique combination of two elements in Sand Green color:

[Slope, Curved 2 x 1 x 1 1/3 with Recessed Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6091&idColor=48#T=C&C=48)

[image]

and [Slope, Curved 4 x 1 Inverted](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=13547&idColor=48#T=C&C=48)

[image]